# How to replace local solution project to nuget

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have a large solution in visual studio. And I have one project (logger), that uses in other all projects of solution. I need to replace this project (logger) in nuget. Because of that i need remove my logger project in solution, and in each project add in packages.config link to logger project in nuget. How can i simplify this work?

Comment: are you asking how to put the code from your logger project into a nuget package? Or are you asking if you can do a bulk update of your project files to add a nuget reference in all of them? The wording is a bit unclear.

Comment: i asking abot how to add nuget reference in all of them, if there was reference in local logger project

Comment: right-click on Solution file (in Solution Explorer), go to Manage Nuget Packages For Solution. You can select a package and then select all that projects within that solution that you want to install it into.

Comment: the problem is that in solution hundred projects, and i don't know where it use. i think i need to write script, which will seek project with reference to local-project and replace it to nuget-version. Or exists another tool to do that

Comment: the proj files are XML, so you should be able to write a script fairly easily that can parse them for a specific token identifying that the project references the logger. Then you can use that to ouput a powershell command string to install the nuget package into those projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could right-click your solution to choose "Project Dependencies" option, and select your logger project in ComboBox. Then the project that reference the logger projects will shown as gray out.
[image]

Then you could know which projects are reference your logger project and remove from these project and install the NuGet packages for these projects through "Manage NuGet Packages For Solutions" that ADyson suggested.